# subscript operator postfix

Tags: c++, binary, subscript

The C++ standard defines the expression using subscripts as a postfix expression. AFAIK, this operator always takes two arguments (the first is the pointer to T and the other is the enum or integral type). Hence it should qualify as a binary operator.

However [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha4ct2b0.aspx) and [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr324.htm) does not list it as a binary operator.

So the question is, what is subscript operator? Is it unary or binary? For sure, it is not unary as it is not mentioned in $5.3 (at least straigt away).

What does it mean when the Standard mentions it's usage in the context of postfix expression?

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to agree with you in that `operator[]` is a binary operator in the strictest sense, since it does take two arguments: a (possibly implicit) reference to an object, and a value of some other type (not necessarily enumerated or integral). However, since it is a bracketing operator, you might say that the sequence of tokens `[x]`, where `x` might be any valid subscript-expression, qualifies as a postfix unary operator in an abstract sense; think currying.

Also, you cannot overload a global `operator[](const C&, size_t)`, for example. The compiler complains that `operator[]` must be a nonstatic member function.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `operator[]` is a binary operator but it is special in that it must also be a member function.

Similar to `operator()`

You can read up on postfix expressions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2az68d4d%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

I just found an interesting article about `operator[]` and postfix expression, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th52k9c8%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the context that [] is used in that counts. Section 5.2.1 the symbol [] is used in the context of a postfix expression that is 'is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))'. In this context, [] isn't an operator. In section 13.5.5 its used to mean the subscripting operator. In this case it's an operator that takes one argument. For example, if I wrote:

```
 x = a[2];
```

It's not necessarily the case that the above statement evaluates to:

```
x = *(a + 2);
```

because 'a' might be an object. If a is an object type then in this context, [] is used as an subscript operator.

Anyway that's the best explanation I can derive from the standard that resolves apparent contradictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a close look to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B it will explain you that standard C++ recognize operator[] to be a binary operator, as you said.
Operator[] is, generally speaking, binary, and, despite there is the possibility to make it unary, it should always be used as binary inside a class, even because it has no sense outside a class.

It is well explained in the link I provided you...
Notice that sometimes many programmers overload operators without think too much about what they are doing, sometimes overloading them in an incorrect manner; the compiler is ease is this and accept it, but, probably, it was not the correct way to overload that operator.

Following guides like the one I provided you, is a good way to do things in the correct manner.

So, always beware examples where operators are overloaded without a good practice (out of standard), refer, first to the standard methods, and use those examples that are compliant to them.