# subscript operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

is *subscript* operator **[ ]** *unary* or *binary* operator ?

I'm quite new to C++ and was going through operator operloading and wondered 
is  subscript a *unary* or *binary*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subscript operator is a binary operator in the strict sense as it takes two arguments, the reference to the object and the value.

```
int arr[3];
```

Here you can see that [] operator makes use of both arr and 3.

Comment: This has been already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302142/subscript-operator-postfix   Read this for a detail explanation

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought .

Comment: what do you wanna say about '->' _pointer to member_ operator ?

Comment: -> is also a binary operator. For more on the operators, check this site : http://www.codingunit.com/unary-and-binary-operator-table

Comment: Since C++23 subscript operator can accept several indices, say, two. Does it make it (in case when two indexes are accepted) ternary operator?

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard

**13.5.1 Unary operators**

> 1 A prefix unary operator shall be implemented by a non-static member
>   function (9.3) **with no parameters**...

and

**13.5.2 Binary operators**

> 1 A binary operator shall be implemented either by a non-static member
>   function (9.3) **with one parameter**...

Thus the subscript operator is a **binary operator**.

The Unary operators in C++ are:

```
unary-operator: one of
    * & + - ! ~
```

and also you may add to unary operators

```
++ cast-expression
-- cast-expression
```